# mysql - count function returns 0 in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, count, xampp

i'm using xampp as a portable server, but only this code isn't working in xampp ..
in my appserv static server this code working perfectly but in xampp it returns 0 in rank field,
this is the code:

```
SELECT m1.*,
  students.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT t2.mark,
      students.class
    FROM students
    INNER JOIN m1 AS t2
    ON students.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE (((students.class) LIKE 'one'))
    ) AS t1
  WHERE t1.mark>=m1.mark
  ) AS rank
FROM m1
INNER JOIN students
ON m1.ID = students.ID;
```

is there something i have to set in the user manual or something ? i found this tow solutions but nothing worked:

```
SET @@SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@SQL_MODE, ',IGNORE_SPACE');

SET @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE, ',IGNORE_SPACE');
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using right condition. ((students.class) LIKE 'one') this means you are looking for students.class = 'one'. Please check how to use like ?

Comment: Fahad Anjum i tried this but still have the problem .. i think the problem from the server because the same code worked in appserv but its not working in xampp but i cant know what to do to make it work

Comment: Have you checked database connections ? Is it same ?

Comment: Fahad Anjum yes database connections is working